# Cannot connect to my Azure SQL database

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms, azure-sql-database, connect

I have been using Azure SQL database for the past six month, and it works very well. But today, I cannot connect to it from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

I got this error:

[image]

I checked my Azure account, the database is still alive:

[image]

Sometimes I get this problem and after 5-10 minutes it is automatically resolved.

I think the problem is at Azure Server.

Any idea to fix this problem for good?

Comment: It might be Azure VPN connection problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for the less than optimal experience. The error message does indicate a service issue. Could you please contact me at mihaelab at Microsoft dot com? I would like to understand why your perceived unavailability in 5-10 min long as per our telemetry none of the databases in the server have such long outages.

Thanks,
Mihaela